# How can i update my react component with the use of hooks in functional way

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a simple clock that updates times every second i am really new to react so i am bit confused how to use hooks in function i am trying this now stuck in how to update setTimer and display update in return function
Thanks in advance

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Timer() {

    const [timer, setTimer] = (useState(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()));
    return (

        <div>
            <h2>It is {timer}.</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Timer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook for that,

```
useEffect(()=>{
    //This will update timer every second
    const interval = setInterval(()=>{
      setTimer(new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
    },1000); 

    //This is important to clear interval
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
},[timer]) //Dependency array, useEffect will run only when timer changes
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-adeoh3)

Comment: () => clearinterval(interval) it is giving an error as Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.eslint(no-unused-expressions)
'clearinterval' is not defined.eslint(no-undef)

Comment: @Avinash, it's `clearInterval` (with capital `I`) check the updated answer.

Comment: still on the same line function clearInterval(intervalId: NodeJS.Timeout): void (+1 overload)
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.eslint(no-unused-expressions)

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTimer(new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
        }, 1000);
        () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [timer])

Comment: @Avinash, It's my bad, forgot to add `return`. Check the updated answer.